# Hydrogen atom Ionization by Magnetic Field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, ionization-energy

The source of a magnetic field (it could be a magnetic dipole) is moving at relativistic speed. This magnetic field encounters a hydrogen atom at rest with respect to the source.
Will this encounter with this hydrogen atom cause it to be ionized? What is the minimum Lorentz factor the magnetic field can have to ionize the hydrogen atom?

Comment: The question "what is the minimum Lorentz factor the magnetic field can have to ionize the hydrogen atom" can be simplified to  "what is the minimum speed the magnetic field must have to ionize a hydrogen atom". While I don't know the answer, it will probably need up to four other parameters to be addressed: 1. How close does the magnet pass the hydrogen atom? 2. What is the strength of magnetic field. 3. atomic hydrogen or molecular hydrogen? 4. From which electron orbit?.